# Why is "Apple silicon" with lowercase "s"?

Tags: apple-silicon, pages

Almost all products of all brands are in title case, including Apple Music, Apple Books etc. Why is "silicon" in lowercase? Perhaps someone has inside info... just curious.

[image: Apple service names]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks “why Apple does something” is considered off-topic as described in the [help].

Comment: *Mac mini* is a product that  doesn’t conform to title case.  Apple doesn’t sell “silicon” per se. They sell Mac computers with processors powered by Apple silicon.

Comment: @Allan thanks, and I don't mind the question being closed as this is just curiosity. As for naming, it doesn't need to be a product to be in title case, it can also be a proprietary technology, like Alfa Romeo Twin Spark.

Comment: It's like saying "Intel Xenon processors."  Instead of using the word "processor" they opted (for whatever reason) to use "silicon."   See the sub-title on [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211814).  It gives you a perfect example of this usage.

Answer (score 4):

Apple silicon is not a registered trademark, where the others are: https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/trademark/appletmlist.html.

Comment: I understand that, though Mac mini is a trademark and follows the same sentence case...